# OwlCarousel with Fade Transition Slides in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I'm using a plugin: [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html)

Here is the set up code I'm using:

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
autoPlay : 5000,
singleItem:true,
transitionStyle : "fade"     
});
```

It uses the "fade" transition in Opera, Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari. Has anyone encountered this before and found a reason and way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

change `line 804` for `owl.carousel.js`:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
```

to

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length > 0);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/n2391aof/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also had this in my CSS:

```
* {     transition:all .2s linear;      -o-transition:all .2s linear;     -moz-transition:all .2s linear;     -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;}
```

So in addition to Dmitriy's solution I just had to add

```
 #owl-demo *  {   transition: none;     -o-transition:none;     -moz-transition:none;     -webkit-transition:none;      }
```